# Where is the mistake in this time dilation derivation?

Tags: special-relativity, time-dilation

Suppose we have two observers, A and B. Observer A moves relative to observer B at a speed of $v_A$. Observer A has a laser beam, and he "shoots" a burst of light. Now let some time measured by A be $t_A$ and some other time for observer B be $t_B$. Assume that when the laser beam is emitted, $t_A = t_B = 0$ and observer A is directly next to B.

The light beam travels a distance $x_L$, and both A and B have now elapsed different times. To prove this, assume that the distance traveled by A relative to B is $x_A$. Now assume that $x_L = ct_A = v_At_B+ct_B$ i.e. both observers see the distance the light has traveled to be the same, but A does not perceive himself to be moving, like B does. We can see that

$ct_A=t_B(v_A+c)$

$\frac{t_A}{t_B} = \frac{(v_A+c)}{c} $

$\frac{t_A}{t_B} = (\frac{v_A}{c})+1$

$t_B = \frac{t_A}{\frac{v_A}{c}+1}$

Or more specifically,

$t_{observer}=\frac{t_0}{1+\frac{v_0}{c}}$

Where $t_0$ is the time elapsed for the observer that does not perceive the light source to be moving, and $v_0$ is the relative velocity between the two observers. This seems incorrect, based on the typical formulation of the time dilation factor where two events are viewed as happening at the same place for one observer and the other observer is the one moving relative.

So my question is, where is the mistake in the derivation? What concept has been misunderstood in relativity or what variable was misinterpreted? Is the derivation, in fact, incorrect? I've been scratching my head over this lately. Any and all help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Sam

Comment: The last equality in $x_L = ct_A = v_At_B+ct_B$ is wrong, what makes you think it is correct?

Comment: Yeah, I agree with Willy Billy. The last equality in the equation listed there looks questionable. You're going to have to justify how you arrived at that.

Comment: That was one I figured would be the problem. I believed (erroneously) that from the perspective of person B, the light beam would move a distance equal to the sum of the change in distance of person A and the distance the photon is travelling. Writing it out, it does sound weird. I'm still just figuring out this relativity business, thanks so much for pointing out the error.

Comment: @SamGallagher - In special relativity, light motion is normally the one thing that is trivially simple to calculate or write an equation for: The speed of light seen by any observer in any inertial reference frame is always the same constant of $c$.